# How can i Update my laravel to latest version(8 or above)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

Currently I am using Laravel 4.2.

I have tried this command - `composer global require  laravel/installer`
It is installing the 4.2 Version itself. I need to update it to the latest version. Any suggestions..

My PHP version is 7.3

Comment: As the creator of [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com), I recommend checking it out to automate this process. Or at least using it to stay up-to-date, once you are on a more recent version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you meant upgrade Laravel installer, just reinstall

```
composer global remove laravel/installer 
composer global require laravel/installer
```

4.2 is the latest version of the installer(not the framework), you could install Laravel framework 8.0 using Laravel installer 4.2
https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/installer

You can create a Laravel 8 project using the below command:

```
laravel new example-app
cd example-app
php artisan --version
```

`php artisan --version` should show the latest version of the Laravel framework

If you meant to upgrade your current Laravel 4.2 project to 8.0, you need to upgrade to 5(5.0 - 5.8) first,  then 6, then 7, and then 8.

Below is how to upgrade from 4.2 to 5.0
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

But the path is too long, it's better to create new latest one and just copy-paste the route and controller.

Comment: Ok.I will try this & let u know.

Comment: Ok.I will try this & let u know.

Comment: Got an error like this:        [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package laravel/installer in a version matching ^8.0

Comment: check on my updated answer, 4.2 is latest version, you could install Laravel framework 8.0 using Laravel installer 4.2

Comment: actually I was alreday having that latest verion of 8 which i installed using the commands given in this answer, but i misunderstood it by seeing laravel framework 4.2 ,actually 4.2 was my framework's version.

Comment: plus your answer, I use this refernce to update from 7 to 8
https://codentino.com/blog/upgrade-to-laravel-8/

Answer (score 4):

As per the [official laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#:%7E:text=The%20recommended%20method%20of%20upgrading,code%20specific%20to%20your%20application.), the recommended way is to create a fresh laravel install and copy the unique application files from your old app to the newly created project